Getting an error when running `scarb build`: error: could not execute process: cargo fetch
Running scarb build in a starknet-foundry project results in an error
error: could not execute process: cargo fetch

Caused by:
    No such file or directory (os error 2)


Using Scarb in a starket-foundry project requires having a Rust toolchain installed.
Install Rust with:
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh

And try to build
